# Rails SASS cache location

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I have standard Rails 4.2 app, without compass.

I found similar question but with compass usage.

Recently in the project directory appears folder ".sass-cache"
All what i want , it's just move it to tmp.

In application.rb tried:

```
module Sirius41
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.sass.cache_location = Rails.root.join('tmp', '.sass-cache').to_s
    ap config.sass
  end
end

sass_options = {:cache_path => Rails.root.join('tmp', '.sass-cache').to_s}
```

But it don't change the cache location.

Rails sass config values:

```
{
 :preferred_syntax => :scss,
   :cache => true,
   :read_cache => true,
   :line_comments => true,
   :load_paths => [],
   :logger => #<Sass::Rails::Logger:0x007f80d9148118     @log_level=:debug>,
   :cache_location => "/home/anton/rubyprojects/sirius42/tmp/.sass-cache"
}
```